# went to extend web application now get error 500 when trying to browse sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I extended my Web Application and now I can't browse to my SharePoint Site.

I restarted the server, even tried removing the sites from IIS but they keep returning.

In my IIS manager it shows up 3 new IIS sites:

> sharepoint - 35600
>
> sharepoint - 41652
>
> **sharepoint - external (the one I made)**

[image: IIS image capture]

How do I delete the Content Database for my SharePoint Site?

My SharePoint is a virtual machine so I can roll it back and have done so but whenever I press extend web application this happens.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried Un-Extending the Web Application?

This can be done by:

- Go to Central Admin > Manage Web Applications
- Select your Web Application
- Click the Delete drop-down menu and select Remove
  SharePoint From IIS Website
- Select which website you wish to remove
  (In your case it looks like it would be SharePoint External)
- Select Yes to Delete IIS Websites

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try with Remove-SPContentDatabase. (if you do not know the GUID of the database use Get-SPContentDatabase) 
Source: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607920(v=office.15).aspx 
Source1: http://moss-net4u.blogspot.it/2012/03/sharepoint-how-to-remove-content.html