# Extend a SharePoint 2013 site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

Hello I am quite new to this depth when it comes to SharePoint so bear with me

when you extend a SharePoint site it creates a new IIS site, but does it also create entry's in a SQL database and if so which database and how do I clear them.

the issue

extended web application - my site got page 500, which i found really odd to begin with

my SharePoint and SQLDB isntances are on separate servers so I used a snapshot on my SharePoint VM to roll it back before it extended the site and it was working again, however if I go to extend a site now it says it cant do it and then when I check in the IIS the sites I placed in there before re-appear eventhough it said it couldn't be extended

How can this be as i have revert the machine before i touched anything to do with extending the web application so i am thinking there must be something entered in the SQL database side that i need to clear out to get it clean again.

this is the error i get.

“The web application could not be extended because an unused zone could not be found. Unextend the web application from the zone that you intend to use for the new IIS web site before performing this operation.”

does any one have an idea what i would need to do?

Many Thanks.

Comment: This feels like a duplicate of your own question here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/95859/went-to-extend-web-application-now-get-error-500-when-trying-to-browse-sharepoin. Or is there a difference in your asking?

Comment: i just wanted to word it better its the same issue

Comment: Should we add this as an edit on your first post instead? :)